# Using 'start "http://ipAddress:Port/"' opens a new command prompt?

Tags: command-line

Okay, so I'm totally confused about what the hell is going on in my command prompt. I'm simply trying to make a script that will minimize the prompt window, open an IP address in the browser, and then run a simple HTTP server command via Python.

I have to run the HTTP server command AFTER the `start` command because if I run the HTTP server first, then the next commands DON'T RUN.

I even went down to installing some old custom `.exe` programs that added little features to fix things like this, but none of them worked correctly...

---

*EDIT*

I actually figured out it was `""` that was causing it to not open the link, but it loads the site BEFORE the HTTP server starts. So my NEW question is: How do I run my `http.server` command BEFORE the `start` command without it not working (Running any command after an HTTP server command won't work since everything after it is never executed.)

*EDIT again*

Thanks again Anaksunaman for the answer, here is my final product for the command: (RunHTTPServer.bat):

```
@echo Off

start "" /min python -m http.server 8000 -b 127.0.0.1

sleep 1

start http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I added --bind to bind it to 127.0.0.1, as sometimes when using http.server, and trying to connect to Localhost:8000, it will say connection failed...

so that, OR remove -b/--bind and simply write your PERSONAL address in that start field.

Comment: That won't work. Command-Prompt cannot start HTTP. Have you tried `start firefox.exe "http://ipAddress:Port"` ? `explorer "http://ipAddress:Port"` may also work for DEFAULT Browser...

Comment: whats the code for starting chrome?

Comment: I guess: `start chrome.exe "http://ipAddress:Port"` or `start "c:\program files\google chrome\chrome.exe http://ipAddress:Port"`.

Comment: No I was doing it wrong, i didnt need quotes, still it wont work because the website is loading before the http server works

Comment: Maybe you need a pause (e.g: `timeout /T 5`) before opening the browser [START-SERVER, PAUSE, START-BROWSER]. Or maybe your python program can start the browser when server-start has finished.

Comment: I already said in my edit you cant execute commands AFTER you start the server unfortunately...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage the `start` command in both your calls. For example, using a batch file in Windows:

```
@echo Off

@rem Start two separate processes via the Windows "start" command.
@rem The second command to open the browser will not be blocked.

@rem start the Python HTTP server with a minimized command window ("/min").
start "" /min python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1

@rem Give the HTTP server a second to start (optional).
sleep 1

@rem Open Firefox to the Python HTTP server instance.
start "" firefox http://localhost:8000
```

Or you can use the almost the exact same commands in Python with the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
#!/Programs/Python37/python

# Start two separate processes via the Windows "start" command.
# The second command to open the browser will not be blocked.

import sys
import subprocess
import time

# "/min" (below) minimizes the spawned command window (Windows).
try:

    subprocess.run('cmd /c start "" /min python -m http.server 8000 --bind 127.0.0.1')
    # subprocess.run('cmd /c start "" /min python http-server.py')

    # Wait for our server to start (optional)
    time.sleep(1)

    # Open our browser
    subprocess.run('cmd /c start firefox http://localhost:8000')

except Exception as err:
    print('')
    print(err)
    sys.exit()
```

On a side note, as you correctly point out in the comments below, you can omit the browser name (e.g. `firefox`) in your `start` command to simply open the website in the default browser for Windows (i.e. `start "" http://localhost:8000` or even just `start http://localhost:8000`).

Comment: wait theres a /min built into windows?

Comment: Technically, it's an option to the [start command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: wow, so why is everyone online saying you require external programs for it? perhaps they didnt know? weird. Well thanks.

Comment: There can be advantages to using other programs or methods, depending on your goals. But for immediately minimizing a window, `/min` works pretty well. In any case, you're welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: Also Anaksunaman, Consider adding --bind 127.0.0.1 to your python command,
or just -b 127.0.0.1 like i did in my edit on my question above... As it helps make sure your browser runs localhost.

sometimes in python (for unknown reasons) it binds to 0.0.0.0 rather than localhost by default.

Comment: I appreciate the tip. =)

Comment: One more thing, when starting the website though, i find that instead of running specificlly 'start "" firefox https://website.blah:port' is less compatible with all users. and saw recently that simply running 'start https://website.blah:port' will open the site in your default browser.

Comment: Absolutely. I suppose I just come from a background where choosing a specific browser is normal, rather than simply using the default browser (even though it's likely the same).